# How to import sklearn in pyscript

Tags: scikit-learn, pyscript

The following is pyscript.toml and main.py in my project directory;

pyscript.toml

```
name = "scikit-learn and matplotlib"
packages = ["scikit-learn", "matplotlib"]
```

main.py

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import numpy as np
# Import the json array from js
from js import arrr

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

After importing sklearn I am getting the following error;

```
 Polyscript: Access to local files
(using [[fetch]] configurations in &lt;py -config&gt;)
is not available when directly opening a HTML file;
you must use a webserver to serve the additional files.
See <a style = " text -decoration: underline; href= "https://github.com/pyscript
on starting a simple webserver with Python.
```

How can i import sklearn or other machine learning packages in pyscript?

Comment: What version of PyScript are you using?

Comment: Latest version 2024.1.1